# Genitive articles vs von

Tags: preposition, genitive

Although the definite article is used in a very similar way, I have noticed that it is often used in German in a way that an English speaker would find to be very counter-intuitive or unnecessary. I am not sure if there is a grammar principle at work that I am not aware of, or if it is simply a matter of pure convention. The following sentence, culled from a german-english dictionary, illuminates a bit of what I am talking about:

> Nach einer langen Phase **der** Besatzung erklärte der Staat seine Unabhängigkeit.
>
> *The country declared independence after a long period **of** occupation.*

From an English perspective, using the definite article here would be confusing and quite awkward (i.e. after a long period of **the** occupation ), namely because we have an indefinite article and definite article as part of the same phrase. But that is precisely what we have in the German, and as far as I can tell, such a mixing of definite and indefinite articles does not seem to be an issue.

My question is: Shouldn't **von** be used here instead? are **von** and genitive **der** interchangeable in this context? How can I be sure when to use one over the other?

Answer (score 3):

> Nach einer langen Phase der Besatzung erklärte der Staat seine Unabhängigkeit.

*Phase der Besatzung* is seen as a fixed phrase, you could drop in the word *Besatzungsphase* instead if you liked that better. However, if you wrote

> Nach einer langen Phase einer Besatzung

the word *einer* would be identified as a number word for *one*, not as the indefinite article.

> Nach einer langen Phase mehrerer Besatzungen

Because of that, phrases with genitive supplements **generally** use the definite article.

---

Replacing genitive supplements with the preposition *von* is only allowed if you are talking about a kind instead of an item, as Thorsten showed.

> Die Einlagerung von Kartoffeln

Here, *Kartoffeln* is a kind. It's not a sack of potatoes you are talking about, but about potatoes in general, and what makes their handling different from e.g. apples. In contrary

> Die Einlagerung der Kartoffeln

talks about a certain pile of potatoes while (caution!)

> Die Kartoffeleinlagerung

talks about the action of stocking potatoes in general.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply the correct use of the Genitive case. It can be found in many variations, like

> Durch die Benutzung eines Rasierers
>   Nach langen Jahren der Enthaltsamkeit

Of course there's also the construction that uses *von*, but I can't think of an example where this is used with a singluar object:

> Durch die Benutzung von Rasierern
>   Die Einlagerung von Äpfeln
>   Der Verkauf von Autos

Comment: "I can't think of an example where this is used with a singluar object": What about "ein Anflug von Müdigkeit" ?